# Generic repository and custom type of entity Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I have the following hierarchy:

```
public interface IIdentifiable<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
     TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity<TKey> : IIdentifiable<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
}


//base entity
public class Entity<TKey> : IEntity<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
}

public class Test1: Entity<long>
{
...
}
```

This is repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T, TKey>
        where T : IEntity<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
      ...
    }
```

This generic repository:

```
public class Repository<T, TKey> : IRepository<T, TKey>
        where T : IEntity<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
...
}
```

This is my generic api controller:

```
public class BaseReadController<T, TKey> : ApiController where T : IEntity<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        private readonly IRepository<T, TKey> _repo;

        public BaseReadController(IRepository<T, TKey> repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }      

        public SingleResult<T> Get([FromODataUri] TKey key)
        {
          var test = _repo.Query().Where(t => t.Id == key);
        }
    }
```

But I get `Cannot apply operator == to operands of type Tkey and TKey`.

I have tried like that:

```
var test = _repo.Query().Where(t => t.Id.Equals(key))
```

But I get a NHibernate exception:

```
message: "Boolean Equals(Int64)"
stacktrace: "   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
type: "System.NotSupportedException"
```

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ provider for NHibernate is having some ... places to improve. And therefore I would not suggest to try to find some way how to replace `.Query().Where(t => t.Id == key);` with something else...

Instead, we should extend our `IRepository` with a native call to `session.Get<T>(key)`

```
public interface IRepository<T, TKey>
    where T : IEntity<TKey>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
  ...
  Get<T>(TKey key)
}
```

and implementation would be like:

```
public class Repository<T, TKey> : IRepository<T, TKey>
        where T : IEntity<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
...
    public virtual Get<T>(TKey key)
    {
        var session = ... // get current session
        var result = session.Get<T>(key);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And finally in our controller:

```
public virtual T Get([FromODataUri] TKey key)
{
    var entity = _repo.Get<T>(key);
    return T;
}
```

Comment: I use `LINQ`. And in the repository I have `Query` method which return: `return Session.Query<T>();` I think `Get` method wouldn't work because I use composite keys. I have tried `Session.Load<>`